# Flutter: Is there any way to clean the contents in CustomPaint?

Tags: android, flutter, setstate, custom-painter, flutter-custompainter

Recently I'm using `CustomPaint` and `CustomPainter` to draw line chart. I want to implement the function that, once I click a `button`, the lines in `CustomPaint` will disappear, just like no lines have been painted.

So what function should I put in the `setState()` of the `button`? Thank for your help.

Comment: *"Flutter: Is there any way to clean the contents in CustomPaint?"* - there is no such thing like clean custom painter - if you had for example two circles drawn, the only way one circle to "disappear" is not to draw it

Comment: So the CustomPaint is not eraserable? It just becomes a picture after painting?